# Windows 7 Professional - when all devices are found and installed?

Tags: windows-7, drivers, device-manager

I have a scenario:
- multiple endpoint machines, each running a copy of Win7 Professional 32 bit;
- I have a prebuilt image of the OS which I deploy to new machines and when needed to old ones;
- there are some scripts that are ran first time the OS boots up;

I have a script that needs to wait until all the devices are found and installed. Is there a way to check if Windows found and installed all drivers to the connected devices? I've tried to wait a certain amount of time but this varies from machine to machine. Any way I can determine that? Powershell, Batch, some registry values?

Comment: I don't know but my guess would be that if the Add New Hardware wizard (Hdwwiz.exe) isn't running then there's nothing to install.

Comment: Will check that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you require is possible, but will take a lot of work.

You could use **WMIC**, with **WHERE** condition and check the status of each specific device.
The problem is that the **WHERE** filter would have to be used on each specific device differently, depending on what parameters of the device are verifiable.

For example:

**wmic NICCONFIG WHERE IPEnabled=true**

Will use the **WHERE** condition to display only the adapters that have the IP protocol active, therefore are correctly functional and active.

**NICCONIFIG** is the main parameter used for NIC interrogations. Each device main type will have a different one.

So what you need to do is make a list of the devices by type, get their main WMIC name and for each get a relevant status attribute that can show if the device is correctly installed or not.

Comment: Ok. I can manage that with some C# but is there a way to enumerate unrecognized devices? The main problem is that I know all the devices and the main image has all the drivers included I just need to check if all were installed.

Comment: Yes, WMIC's Win32_PnPEntity class can list the devices on your system. If you query for devices that have an availability of 11 (not installed) or 12 (install error) you will find exactly those devices.